# How to get shell env vars in self contained Ruby processes that cannot have a precursory export by the user?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, zsh

When I attempt to get `$HISTFILE` within a Ruby process, I get nothing back (`$HISTFILE` => ""). How can I get shell (`zsh` and `bash` specifically) vars within self contained Ruby scripts (gems that provide a shell command)?

Here's the script in context: https://github.com/pawurb/lazyme/tree/fix_histfile

If you check this out and then:

```
cd bin
./lazyme
```

You'll notice that the env `HISTFILE` is not being pulled in.

Answer (score 1):

Export HISTFILE:

```
export HISTFILE; your_ruby_process
```

Comment: @ylluminate You have to then get it with the [ENV hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/ENV.html).

Comment: Alright, so I guess we're really trying to get this to work from a gem so that the user can execute `some_command` without having to actually export any env vars first. I've provided the actual context of this project for more details.